# How to run all JUnit tests with Bazel

Tags: java, maven, junit, bazel

I have been trying to run all JUnit tests in a directory with Bazel. As far as I know, the `java_test` rule is only capable of running a specific class. However, I'm looking for behavior more like `mvn test` which runs all JUnit tests in the project. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 16):

The typical way to organize this is to have a `java_test` rule per Java test class, or per group of related Java test classes. Then `java_test`s can be grouped together using [`test_suite`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#test_suite), if that's something you want to do.

You can run all tests in a package with:

```
bazel test //some/package:all
```

or in a package and its subpackages:

```
bazel test //some/package/...
```

or in the entire workspace:

```
bazel test //...
```

More about target patterns: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#target-patterns

If you just want a `java_test` that runs all the tests in a directory, you can do something like

```
java_test(
    name = "tests",
    srcs = glob(["*Test.java"]),
    deps = [ ..... ],
)
```

but that may or may not be the right thing to do. In particular, if you want to just run one test or one test method (e.g. using `--test_filter`), bazel will still build all the `java_test`'s dependencies. Also, note that `glob`s only glob within a build package, and won't cross over into other packages.

Comment: If I try to run all tests in a directory using `glob`, I get `cannot determine test class`. However, I really just want it to run all tests annotated with `@Test` in the current package. Any advice?

Comment: you'll need a junit test suite (specified in the `test_class` attribute) that discovers the test classes. have a look at the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365464

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but hoping this answer would help others coming across this.

There is now `java_test_suite` rule available in [contrib-rules-jvm](https://github.com/bazel-contrib/rules_jvm?tab=readme-ov-file#java_test_suite) repo. This has convenient features like:

- Running all tests mentioned in sources
- Automatically constructs a lib of shared code in the tests folder
- Support for both JUnit4 and JUnit5